# Равномерное увеличить div относительно его центра мышкой JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возник вопрос: как реализовать растяжение `<div>` относительно его центра.

Например, есть div в котором нарисован круг. Как сделать что бы при растяжке мишкой за край он растягивался относительно центра?
HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

CSS

```
#app {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      .circle {
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background: black;
        border-radius: 100%;
        z-index: 4;
      }
```

JS

```
      function BlueCircleRadius1(Xa, Ya, Xb, Yb) {
        let radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Xa - Xb, 2) + Math.pow(Ya - Yb, 2));
        return radius;
      }
      const appDiv = document.querySelector("#app");
      let count = 4;
      class Circle {
        constructor({ pageX, pageY, circleSize = 10 }) {
          const element = document.createElement("div");
          element.id = 5 - count;
          element.className = "circle";
          element.style.top = `${pageY - circleSize / 2}px`;
          element.style.left = `${pageX - circleSize / 2}px`;
          this.element = element;
        }
        draw = (container) => {
          container.append(this.element);
        };
      }

      appDiv.onmousedown = function (event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains("circle")) {
          const ball = event.target;
          function move(pageX, pageY) {
            ball.style.left = pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
            ball.style.top = pageY - ball.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
            if (count == -1 && event.target.id == "1") {
              var el1 = X1.value;
              var numEl1 = parseInt(el1.match(/\d+/));
              var el2 = Y1.value;
              var numEl2 = parseInt(el2.match(/\d+/));
              var el3 = X2.value;
              var numEl3 = parseInt(el3.match(/\d+/));
              var el4 = Y2.value;
              var numEl4 = parseInt(el4.match(/\d+/));
              let obj = document.getElementById("circleBlue");
              let rad = BlueCircleRadius1(numEl1, numEl2, numEl3, numEl4);
              obj.style.left =
                pageX - Number.parseInt(obj.style.width) / 2 + "px";
              obj.style.top =
                pageY - Number.parseInt(obj.style.height) / 2 + "px";
              obj.style.width = 2 * rad + "px";
              obj.style.height = 2 * rad + "px";
            }
            if (count == -1 && event.target.id == "2") {
              var el1 = X1.value;
              var numEl1 = parseInt(el1.match(/\d+/));
              var el2 = Y1.value;
              var numEl2 = parseInt(el2.match(/\d+/));
              var el3 = X2.value;
              var numEl3 = parseInt(el3.match(/\d+/));
              var el4 = Y2.value;
              var numEl4 = parseInt(el4.match(/\d+/));
              let obj = document.getElementById("circleBlue");
              let rad = BlueCircleRadius1(numEl1, numEl2, numEl3, numEl4);

              obj.style.width = 2 * rad + "px";
              obj.style.height = 2 * rad + "px";

              obj.style.left =
                pageX - Number.parseInt(obj.style.height) / 2 + "px";
              obj.style.top =
                pageY - Number.parseInt(obj.style.width) / 2 + "px";
            }
            let X = document.getElementById(`X${event.target.id}`);
            let Y = document.getElementById(`Y${event.target.id}`);
            X.value = "left = " + " " + String(pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2);
            Y.value = "top = " + " " + String(pageY - ball.offsetWidth / 2);
          }
          function onMouseMove(event) {
            move(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            if (count == 0) {
              console.log("Строй");
            }
          }
          function mouseUp() {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          }
          document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, { once: true });
        } else {
          if (count > 0) {
            let X = document.getElementById(`X${5 - count}`);
            let Y = document.getElementById(`Y${5 - count}`);
            X.value = "left = " + " " + String(event.pageX - 5);
            Y.value = "top = " + " " + String(event.pageY - 5);
            const { pageX, pageY } = event;
            const circle = new Circle({ pageX, pageY });
            circle.draw(appDiv);
            count--;
          }
          if (count == 0) {
            function BlueCircleRadius(Xa, Ya, Xb, Yb) {
              let radius = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(Xa - Xb, 2) + Math.pow(Ya - Yb, 2)
              );
              return radius;
            }
            function LargeBlueCircleDrawing(radius, Ax, Ay) {
              let obj = document.getElementById("app");
              let tmp;
              tmp = document.createElement("div");
              tmp.id = "circleBlue";
              tmp.style.zIndex = 2;
              tmp.style.height = 2 * radius + "px";
              tmp.style.width = 2 * radius + "px";
              tmp.style.borderRadius = "100%";
              tmp.style.position = "absolute";
              tmp.style.left = Ax - radius + 5 + "px";
              tmp.style.top = Ay - radius + 5 + "px";
              tmp.style.background = "blue";
              obj.appendChild(tmp);
            }
            var el1 = X1.value;
            var numEl1 = parseInt(el1.match(/\d+/));
            var el2 = Y1.value;
            var numEl2 = parseInt(el2.match(/\d+/));
            var el3 = X2.value;
            var numEl3 = parseInt(el3.match(/\d+/));
            var el4 = Y2.value;
            var numEl4 = parseInt(el4.match(/\d+/));
            //console.log(numEl);
            LargeBlueCircleDrawing(
              BlueCircleRadius(numEl1, numEl2, numEl3, numEl4),
              numEl1,
              numEl2
            );
            count--;
          }
        }
      };
```

Comment: свойство  `transform: scale();` наверное должно подойти.

Comment: @Armen Вобще оно , но проблема теперь что если я тяну центр круга, у меня точка края не совпадает с краем круга(div).

Comment: Могу приложить код , он его многовато )

Comment: минимальный код скинь, глянем, возможно нужен не  `transform: scale()` а что то еще, это просто первое что пришло в голову

Comment: ты кинул только `<div id="app"></div>` :)

Comment: @Armen добавил код

Comment: немного раскажу что делает код , при тыке мыши появляеться точка на мониторе , и так 4 раза , после чего появитьс круг синий , радиус будет от точки 1 до точки 2 , и вот мне нужно двигать точку 1 и что бы менялся круг относительно точки 2  и аналогично для точки 2 что бы менялся круг относительно точки 1

Comment: в функции MOve я меняю рамер круга, проверка какую точку нажал по id ее нахожу и для точки 1 я сделал реализацию она относительно точки 2 меняет круг , а вот при тыке на кнопку 2 не могу сделать реализацию

Comment: (завтра гляну, разберусь, дам знать)

Answer (score 0):

итак, код слишком жесткий, не смог разобратся + там ошибка есть(тоже не стал разбиратся).

вот рабочий вариант по оси Y(ось X сам доделаеш + появление круга или еще что там было у тебя)

кратко про логику, мы просто берем и каждый раз ресуем новый круг с новым размером вместо того чтобы менять его размер.

```js
const app = document.querySelector('.app')

const appYCenter = Math.round(app.clientHeight / 2)
const appXCenter = Math.round(app.clientWidth / 2)

const createCircle = ({
  container,
  size,
  left,
  top,
}) => {
  const circle = document.createElement('div')

  const divideSize = size / 2

  circle.style.position = 'absolute'
  circle.style.width = `${size}px`
  circle.style.height = `${size}px`
  circle.style.border = '4px solid red'
  circle.style.borderRadius = '50%'
  circle.style.top = `${top - divideSize}px`
  circle.style.left = `${left - divideSize}px`

  createCircle.circle?.remove()
  container.appendChild(circle)

  createCircle.circle = circle
}

createCircle({
  container: app,
  size: 200,
  left: appXCenter,
  top: appYCenter,
})


app.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const borderSize = 4

  const isUp = appYCenter > e.pageY

  let size = isUp ? (appYCenter - e.pageY) * 2 : (e.pageY - appYCenter) * 2

  createCircle({
    container: app,
    size: size - borderSize,
    left: appXCenter,
    top: appYCenter,
  })
})
```

```css
.app {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app">
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**если вдруг что то не получится дай знать, помогу разобратся.**

Comment: Привет, да я сам разобрался уже ! Сделал как мне нужно. Поигрался с transform:scale() и у меня получилось сделать то что я хочу )

Comment: @СергейГеращенко круто!